# Should I only use scalar labels with Keras LSTM?

Tags: keras, lstm, error-handling

I have an array `X_train = (1110,25,2)` and a `y_train = (1110,5,2)`. It means I use arrays with length of 25 for inputs and length of 5 for labels. But when I use:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = 25, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (25, 2))) 
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units = 2))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 100 , batch_size = 25)
```

It gives me this error in the last line of the code:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (1110, 5, 2) [Finished in 5.1s
>   with exit code 1]

The code works if I change the length of `y_train` to the 1, but I like to test longer y labels to train. What is the problem and how can I fix it?

EDIT:
I create `X_train` and `y_train` arrays with this code:

```
for i in range((len(training_set)%30) + 30 , len(training_set) - days ):
    X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-30:i-5])
    y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-5:i])
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
```

This is the result of `model.summary()`

```
model.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_45 (LSTM)               (None, 25, 25)            2800      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_45 (Dropout)         (None, 25, 25)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_46 (LSTM)               (None, 25, 25)            5100      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_46 (Dropout)         (None, 25, 25)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_47 (LSTM)               (None, 25, 25)            5100      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_47 (Dropout)         (None, 25, 25)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_48 (LSTM)               (None, 25)                5100      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_48 (Dropout)         (None, 25)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 52        
=================================================================
Total params: 18,152
Trainable params: 18,152
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

EDIT2:
I have tried to solve my problem with `RepeatVector()` function in `encoder-decoder` approach with the following code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = 25, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (25, 2))) 
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units = 25, return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units = 25)) #, return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(RepeatVector(5))
model.add(LSTM(units = 5 ,return_sequences = True)) 
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units = 5 ,return_sequences = True )) 
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units = 2))
```

But I get this stupid result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Can you post a model summary using:

```
model.summary()
```

Also, elaborate on how exactly the Y_train dataset works with the X_train?  It's not clear how the 25 time steps from X_train data correspond to the Y_train 5 outputs.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question!

Comment: I'm still not clear on what exactly you are trying to predict.  You have a sequence of variable length and want to predict the next 5 timesteps?  Can you elaborate on this?  Also, I assume, given the model.summary output, that you have return_sequences=False on the last lstm layer, correct?

Comment: I am trying to create `X_train` with capturing 25 elements, then shift it 1 position then capture 25 elements till the end of the whole data. And do the same process with length of 5 for `y_train` array.

Comment: Yes, I read data for 25 days, then predict next 5 days.

Comment: Also the last LSTM layer is `return_sequence = False` cause I have connected it to a `Dense(units = 2)` layer that is my last layer.

Comment: Ahhh, ok.  I understand what you are trying to do now.  I believe TimeDistributed will solve your problem.  You are wanting to apply a Dense layer to 5 time-steps, independently.  If you return sequences from the last LSTM layer and put the Dense layer inside a TimeDistributed() wrapper, you will get output of shape (batch_size, 25, 2).  Now, because this is larger in the time-step dimension, you need to reshape your Y data to match this.

Also, you could just reshape the Y data to be of size (samples, 1, 5*2), and just  interpret the results sequentially.  Just change the Dense units to 10

Comment: I've never done the 2nd suggestion, but i don't see why it wouldn't be fine.  I have used a Time Distributed wrapper, but I was interested in all time-step predictions as well as final t+1.  So, it was more fit to my problem exactly.  As far as I know, there is not  way to only use part of the input tensor as input to the TimeDistributed wrapper.  That will take some research.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90220/discussion-between-kylec123-and-user3486308).

Comment: Changing `Dense(2)` to `Dense(10)` didn't solve the problem and I still get same error. I must read about `TimeDistributed()`. I don't know much about it.

Comment: You would need to adjust the shape of your Y-data either way.  Feel free to join the chat if you want.

Comment: My network was working ok with `y_train`s with length of 1 instead of 5. When my code was like this `    y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i])` But I liked to test longer Y labels to make longer predictions.

Comment: To make longer predictions, you could just make a prediction for the next time step and append this value to the end of the previous 24 values, and pass this back in to make another prediction.  Do this 5 times and you would get what you want.  There are many ways to frame the multi-step prediction problem.  I'd think this is the most common way.

Comment: I do what you explained right now, but I thought maybe with longer Y labels I can get more accurate predictions?

Comment: That is a very logical though, I haven't done both and compared results so I'm not too sure.  It seems likely so.  Basically, the key problem is your optimizer expects as input (From the Dense layer) something of size (batch_size, 5, 2) but your Dense layer is only outputting something of size (batch_size, 2)

Comment: I updated my question